# If my answer does not solve the OP's question, should I delete it?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have posted an answer to a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575659/proprietary-drivers-dont-work-for-my-amd-6850m) and linked to my own method for solving it on Ubuntu Forums. The OP has subsequently commented that it does not work for his laptop.

Should I delete my answer or leave it?

Comment: If an answer gets you negative reputation, delete it.  Otherwise, leave it in, as other people can find the same answer afterwards and will upvote it when it solves their problem...  ;-) Once you have 1000 reputation, you will be able to see a [split between down and upvotes](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/established-user).

Comment: I was thinking that having only a small fraction of my answers accepted would have negative implications, regardless of my rep score. Is that not the case?

Comment: Nope, on the contrary: if you have enough non-accepted answers you get a gold badge "unsung hero"...  ;-)

Comment: Usually if it don't solve, and especially if I misunderstood something I usually <strike>answer</strike> since op usually leaves comment that didn't work, so rather than delete and have missing info I strike through the whole thing. Then if I find something else, I update answer.

Comment: @Fabby The description of that badge says the answers have to be accepted.

Comment: @kasperd: more then 10 accepted answers and maximum 25% of total answers accepted... ;-)

Comment: @Fabby It doesn't say maximum 25%, it says more than 25%.

Comment: @kasperd Well, I'll be losing mine soon then as I get about 1 in 6 answers accepted...  ;-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It may solve someone else's related problem, so leave it.

## However

Link-only answers are not welcome here. Please post at least a summary of the steps involved.

Comment: Duly noted. I've edited the original answer, and will keep this in mind for future answers.

Comment: Solutions are usualy a process, requiring multiple steps, and info gathering. Update your answer accordingly.

Comment: I can't update my answer; I have nothing else of use to add. The OP had the same problem that I've had several times on multiple machines. I told him how I solved it. Unfortunately it didn't work for his particular machine.

Comment: @CarlH Consider reposting it as a standalone Q+A if you know it works on other machines so that other people can find it in the future.

Comment: @JorgeCastro I will do but could you elaborate on how to do that, please? I've searched the help pages but am no wiser for it.

Comment: @Carl Post a question, and beneath it will be a check box - along the lines of "Answer your question". See also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @muru  Okay, I've done it:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/579681/ati-driver-for-radeon-6530d 
Is that the right way to do it? (Disclaimer: I've never seen Jeopardy, so the example was wasted on me).

Comment: @CarlH Argh. I meant to add two links and instead copied the same link twice. Here's another post worth going over: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136617/when-should-i-post-a-question-with-the-answer

Answer (score 2):

My opinion would be no.  As a general rule:

It might solve another's issue.

It also might be part of a process of elimination in identifying the solution to an issue.

The record of it having been attempted and not being the answer might streamline future problem-solving of the same/similar issues.

Also there is the social context as well: it is positive for the community to have a history of people working together to solve issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in agreement with Deleuze on this.

Quite often I find that the responses to my questions give enough extra information to develop the solution myself.

In these instances I upvote the helpfull answer(s), and make a comment of what did / didn't work in my case.

then I will 'answer my own question' and attempt to put a complete answer where I can.

Better still if there is one particular answer that helped I would make a comment for the author to add in the additions / modification for my solution, so as I can accept it as the answer.

I guess it is a different problem if you answer is being heavily downvoted, especially if it is being done so without any comments. I always attempt to 'not downvote' but would prefer to put in a comment as to why I think that the answer is bad / wrong / dangerous. Giving the author time to modify the question if he so desires.

I actually have a question (somewhere) which was downvoted, and the initial comment was not helpful as to why the commenter thought it was a bad question. I modified the question, but he refused to say if I had made the question better / more acceptable or not

David